# Retrivig ID of Office 365 word document saved in sharepoint

Tags: office-js

When a Office 365 word document is saved it gets stored in a location in sharepoint with a particular ID (a GUID). Is there any property in the office web api which will let me retrieve this document ID?. I do know that Office.js has the method [Document.getFilePropertiesAsync](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getfilepropertiesasync) which currently returns only the URL of the document. Is there any other method in the Office.js API for retriving document properties.

Answer (score 0):

Excel workbook and Word document objects have a Properties property, but I don't think that GUID is included. I think you probably going to have to use the [SharePoint REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service) or the [Microsoft Graph APIs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview).